# How to choose a mailbox

Tags: delphi, outlook, ms-office

I have two mailboxes in `MS Outlook`. I need to get mail from one of them. How to select a specific mailbox? I have `Office 365` installed. Something needs to be set in `Logon ('', '', true, true);` ?

My code

```
zOutlook := TOutlookApplication.Create(nil);
try
  zOutlook.ConnectKind := ckNewInstance;
  try
    zOutlook.Connect;
    try
      zNameSpace := zOutlook.GetNamespace('MAPI');
      zNameSpace.Logon('', '', true, true);
      try
        zInbox := zNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox);
        zInboxUnread := zInbox.Items.Restrict('[Unread]=true');
        FCodeSite.Send('zInboxUnread.Count ' + IntToStr(zInboxUnread.Count));
        for i := 1 to zInboxUnread.Count do
        begin
            //..
        end;
      finally
        zNameSpace.Logoff;
      end;
    finally
      zOutlook.Disconnect;
    end;

  except
    on E: SysUtils.Exception do
    begin
      FCodeSite.SendError(E.Message);
    end;
  end;
finally
  zOutlook.Free;
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed your code.

The idea is to iterate the folders at two levels: the mailboxes and the folders in the mailboxes.

Tested with Oultook 2019. Should work with other versions as well.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
    zOutlook     : TOutlookApplication;
    zNameSpace   : _NameSpace;
    zInbox       : MAPIFolder;
    zFolder      : MAPIFolder;
    zInboxUnread : _Items;
    I            : Integer;
    Found        : Boolean;
    MailBoxName  : String;
    InboxName    : String;
begin
    MailBoxName := 'francois.piette@company.com';
    InboxName   := 'Boîte de réception';
    zOutlook := TOutlookApplication.Create(nil);
    try
      zOutlook.ConnectKind := ckNewInstance;
      try
        zOutlook.Connect;
        try
          zNameSpace := zOutlook.GetNamespace('MAPI');
          zNameSpace.Logon('', '', true, true);
          try
            Found := FALSE;
            for I := 1 to zNameSpace.Folders.Count do begin
                zFolder := zNameSpace.Folders.Item(I);
                if SameText(zFolder.Name, MailBoxName) then begin
                    Found := TRUE;
                    break;
                end;
            end;
            if not Found then
                Exit;

            Found := FALSE;
            for I := 1 to zFolder.Folders.Count do begin
                zInbox := zFolder.Folders.Item(I);
                if SameText(zInbox.Name, InboxName) then begin
                    Found := TRUE;
                    break;
                end;
            end;
            if not Found then
                Exit;
            zInboxUnread := zInbox.Items.Restrict('[Unread]=true');
            for i := 1 to zInboxUnread.Count do begin
                //..
            end;
          finally
            zNameSpace.Logoff;
          end;
        finally
          zOutlook.Disconnect;
        end;
      except
        on E: System.SysUtils.Exception do begin
          Memo1.Lines.Add(E.Message);
        end;
      end;
    finally
      zOutlook.Free;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: It is not a good idea to rely on the folder name - default folder names are localized. `Store.GetDefaultFolder` is a better alternative.

Answer (score 2):

Loop though the `Namespace.Stores` collection and call `Store.GetDEefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)`  instead of `NameSpace.GetDefaultFolder`.

You might want to look at the `Store.ExchangeStoreType` property to make sure you only process primary Exchange mailboxes.